# Change app volume with out changing master volume in the system

Tags: android

I have an application where i want to change app volume with out changing master volume of the device.I have attached code here. using this code if we change volume from an app, system volume get changed. is there any other way i can handle that?

```
enter code here

private Dialog showVolumeChangeableDialog()
{
    Dialog dialog = new Dialog(getActivity());
    dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.volume_changeable_dialog);
    muteUnMuteButton=(Button)dialog.findViewById(R.id.volume_mute);
    muteUnMuteButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    volumeSeekbar = (SeekBar)dialog.findViewById(R.id.volume_seekBar);
    volumeSeekbar.setMax(audioManager.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC));
    setVolumeProgressState();
    volumeSeekbar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(this);
    changeStateIfRequired(audioManager.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC));

    WindowManager.LayoutParams lp = new WindowManager.LayoutParams();
    lp.copyFrom(dialog.getWindow().getAttributes());
    lp.width = WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
    lp.height = WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
    lp.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;
    dialog.getWindow().setAttributes(lp);

   // dialog.show();
    return dialog;
}

@Override
public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser)
{
    audioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,progress, 0);
    changeStateIfRequired(progress);
}

@Override
public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar)
{

}

@Override
public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar)
{

}
```

Comment: Save the original volume before you change it, and restore it at the same time as you release audio focus.

Answer (score 0):

You can save the current volume using:

currentVol = audioManager.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);

and then change the volume according to your requirement. And restore the saved volume when you dismiss the dialog.

Answer (score 0):

By using below code we can take complete control, First implements your activity with  OnAudioFocusChangeListener

> //Checking HeadSet is plug-in or not

```
AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager)getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE); 
        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        boolean isHeadSeton=audioManager.isWiredHeadsetOn();
        audioManager.setMode(isHeadSeton?AudioManager.MODE_IN_COMMUNICATION:AudioManager.MODE_IN_COMMUNICATION);
        audioManager.setSpeakerphoneOn(!isHeadSeton);
        this.setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
```

//set Medium Volume for Speaker

```
audioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_VOICE_CALL, 3, 0);
```

// 3 can vary device-to-device so, calculate it dynamically and pass it.

This code we can also use within BroadCastReciever(for headset plug-in or plug-out) or inside oncreate() method like -

```
HeadsetConnectionReceiver headset=new HeadsetConnectionReceiver();
        registerReceiver(headset, new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_HEADSET_PLUG));
```

> //App is taking control over other audios(Background musics,FM etc...)

```
int req=audioManager.requestAudioFocus(this, AudioManager.STREAM_SYSTEM, AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN);
```

Now in OnPause() Method release the audio focus

```
audioManager.abandonAudioFocus(this);
```

**and set Volume to the Normal.**

reference link- http://developer.android.com/training/managing-audio/audio-focus.html